# Сокращение логических операций

Tags: логика

Как можно сократить такое выражение (если можно, поподробнее) ?

```
(a && b && !d) || !a || !b || d || c
```

Comment: Почитайте про «карты Карно» и вообще про минимизацию булевых функций.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

0) `(a && b && !d) || !a || !b || d || c`

1) `!(a && b && !d)` --> `!a || !b || d`

Таким образом имеется выражение вида (`X||!X||c`)

```
(a && b && !d) ||!(a && b && !d)|| c
```

2) Вот это  `(a && b && !d) ||!(a && b && !d)` -- всегда верно ( `X||!X=1` )

3) Получаем выражение `1||c` которое тоже всегда верно

То есть можно просто сократить до `1` ( `true`)

Comment: да. Вы правы. так что сразу до true можно сокращать.

Comment: остается только `С`, которая и влияет на результат

Comment: @SeniorAutomator  `1 || C = 1` то есть не влияет

Comment: @Batanichek точно, или не заметил